# Can't get OpenFL URLLoader to work on Android (works fine with Haxe/Neko)

Tags: android, json, haxe, openfl

I have an Android app that I've written in Haxe that uses openfl.net.URLLoader to fetch the JSON for an array (it's a game and the high scores are stored on a web server). I'm using FlashDevelop 5.1.1.1 for the IDE.

When I compile the app to Neko it runs fine and gets the JSON string from the webserver no problem.

When I compile to Android and install it on my phone, it never contacts the webserver. I have the webserver notify me when any page is loaded, so I know the server is never being reached at all by the Android app.

The app has the INTERNET permission, as specified in the Project.xml:

That's really redundant though since I'm also using the In-App Purchase extension for openfl (extension.iap.IAP), which automatically adds the INTERNET permission (and works just fine).

For completeness, here's the code:

```
var urll:URLLoader = new openfl.net.URLLoader();
urll.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){
    // Parses JSON result here -- this code is never reached.
}
urll.load(new URLRequest("http://example.com/?action=highscores"));
```

I also tried to use haxe.Http.requestUrl, which works perfectly in Neko, I get an "invalid socket handle" error.

Any ideas about what I'm missing? Again, works perfectly in Neko, fails to fetch the page on Android.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What if instead of local variable var urll:URLLoader use class member, and remove anonymous function?
Or as alternative use [haxe.Http](http://api.haxe.org/haxe/Http.html)

Comment: As I said in the question, haxe.Http crashes with an "invalid socket handle" error. As to the other suggestions, can you be more clear? All of the examples I've seen posted everywhere use a local variable and some use an anonymous function. And as I said, it works fine in Neko, just not Android. I'll try removing the anonymous function just in case that has something to do with it.

Comment: Not using an anonymous function had no effect. Still works fine in Neko, still fails in Android.

Comment: I realized what you meant about using a class member, so I switched to that instead of a local variable but it had no effect on Android either.

Comment: Try
`var httpQuery:Http = new Http(url);
httpQuery.onError = onError;
httpQuery.onData = onData;
httpQuery.request(false);

function onError(msg:String) 
{
}
function onData(data:String)
{
}`

Comment: Any error or warnings in android logs?
Try to trace on IOErrorEvent for instance
`urll.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urll.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);`

Comment: I added the code you suggested and got the same error, "Invalid socket handle". I am running version 3.6.1 of OpenFL.